# Creating a Registration Form in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list

I need help with this task. I would like to create an app/webpart in SharePoint 2013 Foundation that displays a list of events. Users can see this and if interested can signup for which ever event by clicking or filling out a form. Once the action is completed from the user, they are automatic added to the event. There will be a "status" column stating OPEN or CLOSED. Once CLOSED it will no longer be display or will not accept new registrations.

I have tried this with two custom lists but the issue is the chance for users to cause errors (the user might not type their last name). Also there is no way to automaticly increase the number of attendees by one once the user completes the registration. I have also tried getting the data of the user ID, checking how many IDs are listed, display the number and calculate if its < or = to the total number stated (to determine if the event is OPEN or CLOSED) but calculated column will display the only the first ID number.

I also tried creating a survey, taking the responses from the survey and updating a custom list but it wasn't working either.

I can't figure out how to approach this or maybe should see a different way of approaching this.

I attached an image of what I'm trying to say visually.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this with code but I am assuming you want an out of the box solution. There will have to be compromises...

I think the issue with your approach is that you are only checking whether or not the event is open on be the user is in the sign up form. A different approach could be:

Events list contains list of events

Each event has its own associated list holding registered users

Events list has a calculated column which contains a formula. The formula will look at the status field, if status is open the calculated column will return a url. If the status is closed the formula will return nothing, or a message saying registration is closed.

In order for this to work your lists will need a consistent naming convention in order for the formula to consistently generate a valid url.

Tal

Comment: [quote]    The formula will look at the status field, if status is open the calculated column will return a url.[/quote]

What is the url you are referring to? The event?

Comment: or if there is a way to code this, could you point me to how to do so.

Comment: I am not great with calculated formula syntax but the basic structure would be ad follows:

Comment: oh no, I was referring to what you said. "You could solve this with code but I am assuming you want an out of the box solution". Unless the code you were talking about was the formula

Comment: Iam not great with calculated formula syntax but the basic structure would be as follows:       if status=open(http://mysite/[Title]) if status=closed(sorry event is closed)

Comment: This syntax is totally wrong but you get the idea

Comment: With code there are a million ways... my preference is client side code(javascript). You could pretty easily put a piece of javascript that checked the value of the status field and if it was open provide a link to the registration lists new item form

Comment: maybe this link points to a relevant solution? http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/building-a-registration-sign-up-solution-in-sharepoint